# How do I use H-Screen in Tailwind without extending the page size? (I have a navbar at the top

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have PanelMaster, Panel 1 and Panel 2 components

PanelMaster: flex

Panel1: flex-col

Panel2: flex-col

I have a Navbar component that has 'h-1/5' applied to it at the top of the page.

I am trying to make Panel Master and it's children fill the REMAINING height of the screen. I don't want to make the user scroll anywhere. The only thing that gets me close is 'h-screen', which I would assume works but because of my Navbar, it extends below the limit that adds scrolling to the browser.

Can anyone help?

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div class="App">
      <Navbar></Navbar>
      <PanelMaster></PanelMaster>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Panel 1

```
import React from "react";

const Panel1 = () => {
    return(
        <div className="flex-col">
                <div>Test</div>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Panel1;
```

Panel 2

```
import React from "react";

const Panel2 = () => {
    return(
        <div className="flex-col">
            <p>2</p>
            <p>2</p>
            <p>2</p>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Panel2;
```

Panel master is a simple horizontal flex box to display these 2 components, how can I make it fill the REMAINING screen without adding scroll.

EDIT: Panel Master code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Panel1 from './Panel1.tsx';
import Panel2 from './Panel2.tsx';

const PanelMaster = () => {
    return(
        <div className="flex">
            <div className="bg-pink-500 w-4/5">
                <Panel1></Panel1>
            </div>
            <div className="bg-green-500 w-1/5">
                <Panel2></Panel2>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};

export default PanelMaster;
```

Navbar code

```
import React from "react";

const Navbar = () => {
    return(
        <div className="flex h-1/6 bg-blue-500">
            <div className="grow">
            <button className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold w-full h-full rounded">Test</button>
            </div>
            <div className="grow">
            <button className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold w-full h-full rounded"/>
            </div>
            <div className="grow">
            <button className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold w-full h-full rounded"/>
            </div>
            <div className="grow">
            <button className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold w-full h-full rounded"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: Could you provide the code for `PanelMaster` and `Navbar` please?

Comment: @Wongjn I have added them in the edit mate, cheers.

Comment: You say in your post you "have a Navbar component that has 'h-1/5' applied to it" but I can see that in your edit, the `Navbar` seems to have `h-1/6` applied – could you rectify this discrepancy please? Which one is the truth please?

Comment: I just fixed it, Panel Master was using 'h-screen'. I guess that applied a 'set' viewport value to add below the navbar. I changed it to h-5/6 to reflect the navbars h-1/6.

Comment: Apologies @Wongjn see my above reply, it was 1/6, and the PanelMaster was wrongly, h-screen.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to use the grow in conjunction with min-h-screen.

```
<div className="flex flex-col min-h-screen">
  <NavBar />
  <BigComponent className="grow" />
  <Footer />
</div>
```

This would put NavBar at the Top of the screen, Footer at the bottom of the screen, and BigComponent will fill the remaining space. Should BigComponent grow bigger than the available space, it will push footer down below the fold so it has all the room it needs to display the content.